# Creating a ZIP archive from a Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, zip, archive

Are there Objective-C classes that are equivalent to the ones contained in the Java package `java.util.zip`?
Is to execute a CLI command the only alternative?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of iOS8/OSX10.10 there is a built-in way to create zip archives using `NSFileCoordinatorReadingOptions.ForUploading`. A simple example of create zip archives without any non-Cocoa dependencies:

```
public extension NSURL {

    /// Creates a zip archive of the file/folder represented by this URL and returns a references to the zipped file
    ///
    /// - parameter dest: the destination URL; if nil, the destination will be this URL with ".zip" appended
    func zip(dest: NSURL? = nil) throws -> NSURL {
        let destURL = dest ?? self.URLByAppendingPathExtension("zip")

        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var isDir: ObjCBool = false

        let srcDir: NSURL
        let srcDirIsTemporary: Bool
        if let path = self.path where self.fileURL && fm.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir) && isDir.boolValue == true {
            // this URL is a directory: just zip it in-place
            srcDir = self
            srcDirIsTemporary = false
        } else {
            // otherwise we need to copy the simple file to a temporary directory in order for
            // NSFileCoordinatorReadingOptions.ForUploading to actually zip it up
            srcDir = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString)
            try fm.createDirectoryAtURL(srcDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let tmpURL = srcDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.lastPathComponent ?? "file")
            try fm.copyItemAtURL(self, toURL: tmpURL)
            srcDirIsTemporary = true
        }

        let coord = NSFileCoordinator()
        var error: NSError?

        // coordinateReadingItemAtURL is invoked synchronously, but the passed in zippedURL is only valid 
        // for the duration of the block, so it needs to be copied out
        coord.coordinateReadingItemAtURL(srcDir, options: NSFileCoordinatorReadingOptions.ForUploading, error: &error) { (zippedURL: NSURL) -> Void in
            do {
                try fm.copyItemAtURL(zippedURL, toURL: destURL)
            } catch let err {
                error = err as NSError
            }
        }

        if srcDirIsTemporary { try fm.removeItemAtURL(srcDir) }
        if let error = error { throw error }
        return destURL
    }
}

public extension NSData {
    /// Creates a zip archive of this data via a temporary file and returns the zipped contents
    func zip() throws -> NSData {
        let tmpURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString)
        try self.writeToURL(tmpURL, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic)
        let zipURL = try tmpURL.zip()
        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let zippedData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: zipURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
        try fm.removeItemAtURL(tmpURL) // clean up
        try fm.removeItemAtURL(zipURL)
        return zippedData
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but what about the other way around? That is, having a zip file and then reading its contents as if it is a directory?

Comment: I looked but could not find any similar method to go the other way around.  I've up-voted this answer because it is amazing.  However, in my Mac app, I instead used NSTask to invoke /usr/bin/zip and /usr/bin/unzip.  It is straightforward, offers a lot of *documented* options to control the behavior, and in my case took less code than this.

Comment: Why isn't this approach more widespread? A built-in solution with no need of any extra library you need to maintain, perfect. "Translated" it to objective c and it seems to work as well.

Answer (score 11):

Aside from reading and writing zip archives in your own process, there's no shame in using NSTask to run `zip` and `unzip`.

Comment: Using this method would allow to not change the code to support new features. I wonder what exactly does Finder when you select a file/directory, and then select "Compress" from the menu. Which executable does Finder uses?

Answer (score 9):

- There is a zip-framework, http://code.google.com/p/zip-framework/, but it seems to be in an early (version 0.1) stage.
- Others answers on [cocoadev](http://www.cocoadev.com): [http://cocoadev.com/ZipArchiveLibraryForCocoa](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ZipArchiveLibraryForCocoa)
- One answer from there: ZipKit, https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit

Comment: ZipKit seems to better name its methods than ZipArchive (even if I don't understand why it prefixes its addition methods).

Comment: Prefixing or suffixing category methods help avert name collisions if Apple ever adds a method in Cocoa under the same name.

Comment: ZipKit is now at https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit and no longer on bitbucket (shocker)

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/. It's a class for zipping files. Google is your friend!

Answer (score 2):

Translated the [answer of @marcprux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723162) to Objective-C. Please credit his answer if this is of use for you:

**NSURL+Compression.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSURL (NSURLExtension)

- (NSURL*)zip;

@end
```

**NSURL+Compression.m**

```
#import "NSURL+Compression.h"


@implementation NSURL (NSURLExtension)


-(NSURL*)zip
{
  BOOL   isDirectory;
  BOOL   hasTempDirectory = FALSE;
  NSURL* sourceURL;

  NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  BOOL           fileExists  = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.path isDirectory:&isDirectory];

  NSURL* destinationURL = [self URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];

  if(fileExists && isDirectory)
  {
    sourceURL = self;
  }

  else
  {
    sourceURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:sourceURL withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString* pathComponent = self.lastPathComponent ? self.lastPathComponent : @"file";
    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:self toURL:[sourceURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent] error:nil];

    hasTempDirectory = TRUE;
  }

  NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];

  [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:sourceURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingForUploading error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL* zippedURL)
   {
    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:zippedURL toURL:destinationURL error:nil];
   }];

  if(hasTempDirectory)
  {
    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:sourceURL error:nil];
  }

  return destinationURL;
}


@end
```

---

**NSData+Compression.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSData (NSDataExtension)

- (NSData*)zip;

@end
```

**NSData+Compression.m**

```
#import "NSData+Compression.h"
#import "NSURL+Compression.h"


@implementation NSData (NSDataExtension)


// Creates a zip archive of this data via a temporary file and returns the zipped contents
// Swift to objective c from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723162/
-(NSData*)zip
{
  NSURL* temporaryURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
  [self writeToURL:temporaryURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
  NSURL* zipURL = [temporaryURL zip];

  NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSData*        zippedData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:zipURL options:NSDataReadingMapped error:nil];

  [fileManager removeItemAtURL:temporaryURL error:nil];
  [fileManager removeItemAtURL:zipURL error:nil];
  
  return zippedData;
}


@end
```

Please let me know any improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap), my fast zip file I/O library.

Answer (score 0):

Also: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory