# Attach iCal File in MFMailComposerController?

Tags: iphone, icalendar, eventkit

I want to add Event in my **iPhone Calendar**, i Successfully add the Event in my iPhone calendar. But, i want to get the all Current Month event and i want to attach that **Event file (.ical)** in my **MFMailComposer**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading events is very simple.

```
// Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startOfTheMonth
                                                        endDate:endOfTheMonth
                                                      calendars:nil];
// Fetch all events that match the predicate
NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

More information in [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1).

To get start and end of the month you can use example from this project: https://github.com/melsam/NSDateCategoryForReporting

And use this as an example how to export Events to .ical file
https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/EKEventToiCal/blob/master/EKEventToiCal/

To send .ical file use the code from IronManGill answer but change mimeType to text/calendar

```
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/calendar" fileName:@"/abc.ical"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I can offer you a workaround. If you get the **.ical file** , have access to it. You could convert it into a **.zip file** , please go through these links :-

[How can I create a zip file by using Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c)

[How to zip folders in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150185/how-to-zip-folders-in-iphone-sdk)

[Creating zip files in ObjectiveC for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161327/creating-zip-files-in-objectivec-for-iphone)

And then attach it alongwith the **email** in the `MFMailComposer` using this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *WritableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];    
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:WritableDBPath];    
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"/abc.zip"];
[picker setSubject:@"Database"];    
[picker setMessageBody:@"Database testing" isHTML:NO];    
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.