# Creating a file bundle on OSX

Tags: macos, zip, bundle, macos-carbon, file-extension

For an application I would like to store a collection of files together, and have them appear in the filesystem as a single file so its easy to manage. I am currently storing everything in a folder.

I would like to keep things accessible so you can manually edit the inside contents if neccesary.

One way to do this would be to create a zip archive and give it a custom extension other then .zip. Then it appears as a filetype and if needed you can unpack and access the content, but for normal use keep it hidden.

I can't seem to find a convenient way to do this. Boost and zlib can do the compression but don't work with archives. I found libzip but I have a hard time understanding how to use it and to me it seems that it only reads/writes zip archives without doing the actual compression.

Is there a more convenient way to tackle this?

Can you call system functions for creating an archive on OSX from c++ / Carbon?

Is there another way to make a folder appear as a single file?

Comment: Do you want to create .zip archives from the command line or from within some code you are writing?

Comment: From code (C/C++). Note that I don't really care about the compression. I just want the files to become bundles and stay accessible at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OSX, you can create [Document Packages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#) (similar to application bundles) which are treated as a single file in the Finder, but are really just directories with some internal structure.

Apple does not zip these packages, but they do provide the functionality you describe and they can be created and accessed through CoreFoundation by using [CFBundleRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html) .

From the documentation:

> ... The important thing to remember about creating a document package is that it is just a directory. As long as the type of the document package is registered (as described in [“Registering Your Document Type”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW3)), all you have to do is create a directory with the appropriate filename extension. (The Finder uses the filename extension as its cue to treat the directory as a package.) You can create the directory (and create any files you want to put inside that directory) using the standard BSD file system routines ...

Comment: Thanks. That seems like the way to go. My first target platform is Mac, but I would prefer a solution which is cross-platform. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I have no experience on any other platform, so I won't be much help there. If cross-platform is the goal, perhaps a .zip archive *would* be the better choice. Either that, or write your own binary file format.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @0x80: Some .zip answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928162/creating-a-zip-archive-from-a-cocoa-application

Comment: I got libzip to work after all. My code had a stupid bug. I investigated the other zip libraries in the meantime but none of them seemed to be a better choice. I still very much prefer the bundle approach but I know I need to port this to Windows sooner or later. Any idea how bundles hold up in Windows? I guess they just appear as folders there, or is there a similar initiative in Microsoft land that would be compatible?

Comment: Possibly this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx but that's just a google guess `:)`

Answer (score 4):

As 1st step, simple rename the folder and add the extension `.bundle`, e.g. Myappdir.bundle

That's will show the whole folder as one file with a lego-like bundle icon.

The next step is you must create one Info.plist file inside.