# Objective-C zip library which will zip and unzip, with password protection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a zip libary which will zip and unzip, with password protection ?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question with examples is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150185/how-to-zip-folders-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/). It supports password protection.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Objective-ZIP](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/). Simple to use, works on Mac OS X and iOS, and has support for password-protected ZIP archives. It's also pretty efficient.

EDIT: The google code link is a 404 now. I think this is the new URL for the same project: https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

Comment: Just to clarify for others looking into this solution. Just spent the past 3 days screwing around with this library. It has some major issues with password support, and I do NOT recommend as of the time of this writing.

Comment: How does it? I got the project from git on 6 Feb 2014.  what should we use as crc32: ?
I have tried a lot but when I try to open the zip with an app on my Mac, it says that the password is wrong.

Comment: This is a very old answer, but it comes as my first search result, so I'm leaving this: Objective-Zip defines NOCRYPT and NOUNCRYPT to disable encryption since it's considered weak."_Weak encryption code in MiniZip library was explicitly disabled by removing crypt.h and defining NOCRYPT and NOUNCRYPT_"

Answer (score 2):

Question is old but I hope this library can help someone [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)

Comment: Doesn't support creation of password protected zips