# How to set the password for unzip file in ios

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obj-C, zip libary which will zip and unzip, with password protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313571/obj-c-zip-libary-which-will-zip-and-unzip-with-password-protection)

iam developing one application.In that if i save the unzip folders in Document directory then that information is accessed with user using iExplorer.So i want to set the password for that unzip files.SO please tell me how to set the password for that unzip files.

Comment: What are you trying to protect? You should look into proper encryption mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use [ZipAcrhive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/). Then you would save a zip file with a password using:

`-(BOOL) CreateZipFile2:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password;`

And then you could open it using:

`-(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password;`

And

`-(BOOL) UnzipFileTo:(NSString*) path overWrite:(BOOL) overwrite;`