# Creating a ZIP file from a folder in documents directory - Objective C (ARC)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, compression, automatic-ref-counting

I have an iPhone application that I have developed using ARC.  I have a folder that contains a heap of images in my documents directory that I need to zip up and e-mail.  My project uses ARC.

Does anyone have any example code/links to a resource that would be helpful to me?

I've been raking around online and what I can find is not compatible with ARC - even when it claims to be.

Comment: You know that you can turn off ARC on a file-by-file basis, correct? So if you have non-ARC code you like, you can still use that in an ARC project. ARC is not all-or-nothing; it's a per-file compiler option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: And to further clarify, if you have a Xcode project that builds such an Objective-C library, and its not ARC, you can include that project in your project and use the library, regardless if its ARC or not.

Comment: Oh, no I wasn't aware of that, cheers.

Comment: Maybe check out this built-in way to create a ZIP file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723162

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download and drag the Objective-Zip, MiniZip and ZLib drag in to your project from this link http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/downloads/list (Objective-zip). import the files: 
ZipFile.h,
ZipException.h,
FileInZipInfo.h,
ZipWriteStream.h,
ZipReadStream.h,
zlib.h

Use this code. Please see below:

```
NSString *stringPath1 = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *FileName=[stringPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your file name"];


    NSString *stringPath=[stringPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Your file name" stringByAppendingFormat:@".zip"]];
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:FileName error:&error];
    ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc]initWithFileName:stringPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

    for(int i = 0;i<files.count;i++){

        id myArrayElement = [files  objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"add %@", myArrayElement);

        NSString *path = [FileName stringByAppendingPathComponent:myArrayElement];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
        NSDate *Date = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

        ZipWriteStream *streem = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:myArrayElement fileDate:Date compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [streem writeData:data];
        [streem finishedWriting];
    }

    [zipFile close];
```

Comment: sorry but the link you provided is dead by now.

Comment: Found a working link to this project: https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip