# iOS Objective-Zip corruption issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, objectivezip

I am using **flyingdolphinstudio's Objective-Zip** which is an Objective-C zipping library. I am using this to zip a .txt file following the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649468/creating-a-zip-file-from-a-folder-in-documents-directory-objective-c-arc).

For my case, I do not have an array to cycle through so just for a single file I have the following:

```
ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zip_file_name mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:txt_file_name error:&error];
NSDate *Date = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

NSData *filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:txt_file_name];

ZipWriteStream *stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:txt_file_name fileDate:Date compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
[stream writeData:filedata];
[stream finishedWriting];

[zipFile close];
```

The zipping process seems to work, I get a .zip file with the **correct name** and a **non-zero** size. However, when I try and un-zip this on my mac, it runs into a .cpgz loop. And judging by [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/), I presume its because my file is getting corrupted somewhere in there. Also when I upload it to a server and we try to open it on a linux machine, it spits it back out at us with the error:

> $ unzip COCR2_100.zip 
>   Archive:  COCR2_100.zip
>     End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.
>   note:  COCR2_100.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
>   unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of COCR2_100.zip or
>           COCR2_100.zip.zip, and cannot find COCR2_100.zip.ZIP, period.

Which also suggests it is corrupted.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it may be getting corrupted? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by switching to a different Zip client. Moved from **Objective-Zip** to **ZipArchive** and that seemed to work just fine.