# How to create zip of folder and file in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

[image]

I can able to zip the multiple pdf files and individual folder . But failed to create zip folder of a file and folder which i marked in my screenshot.here is my code . In the If condition i write the code for creating zip file for a folder and in else i write code for files . If i select one file and folder , I need to create zip file of both folder and file in single zip file .

```
     if([[[[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PdfName"] pathExtension]isEqualToString:@""]){

        // For Folder - It creates a zip file in document directory .

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir=NO;
    NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: docDirectory];
    NSString *exportPath = [[mailArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PdfPath"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:exportPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
                            directoryContents = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:exportPath];
                        }
       archivePath = [exportPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", [[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PdfName"]]];

      ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
      [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
       for(NSString *path in directoryContents)
        {
           NSString *longPath = [exportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:longPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir)
             {
                NSString * extension = @"pdf";
                 if ([[longPath pathExtension]isEqualToString:@""]||[[[longPath pathExtension]lowercaseString]isEqualToString:extension]) {
                                    [archiver addFileToZip:longPath newname:path];
                                }
                }
         }
       BOOL successCompressing = [archiver CloseZipFile2];
       if(successCompressing)
         NSLog(@"Success");
        else
         NSLog(@"Fail");

        NSString *path = archivePath;
        [pdfData appendData:[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: path]];
 }
 else{
         // For Single or Multiple pdf files - It creates a zip file in document directory .
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     isFolder = YES;
     archivePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/pdfMarkup.zip"];
     ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
     [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
     for (int i =0; i<[mailArray count]; i++)
      {
        [archiver addFileToZip:[[mailArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PdfPath"] newname:[[[mailArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PdfName"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""]];

       }
     BOOL successCompressing = [archiver CloseZipFile2];
     if(successCompressing)
       {
          NSLog(@"Zipp successfull");
       }
       else
       {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"message:@"Cannot zip Docs Folder"delegate:nilcancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                            [alert show];
       }

     NSString *path = archivePath;
     [pdfData appendData:[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: path]];
}
```

Comment: Got the solution., I copied the folder and file to temporary folder and zipped that folder. after compressing , i deleted the temporary folder.

Comment: Maybe check out this built-in way to create a ZIP file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723162